# Unable to run F# correctly in LINQPad

Tags: f#, linqpad

```
let isValid n =
    let valid, _ = Int32.TryParse(n)
    valid

let validateInput input =
    List.forall (fun i -> isValid i)

let n = validateInput [| "1"; "2"; "3", "fwfuwe", "adijqw" |]
n.Dump()
```

I have some code which will determine if user input numbers are valid numbers (simulated here with an array) and if they are then return true.

However when I try run it in LINQPad I get some internal LINQPad information being displayed. I think it's because I'm not calling the functions correctly.

This is what I get:

[image]

Comment: `validateInput` doesn't pass the `input` argument to the `List.forall`, so what the `validateInput` function returns is a function that's waiting for the input. If you change its implementation to `List.forall (fun i -> isValid i) input`, it should behave as expected.

Comment: You're right, I totally missed that.